# I have to check recursivley if the value exists in collection Python3.0

Tags: python

I wrote a the code below to check if a given value exists in a given collection.
For some reason, I get always 'False'; why does this happen, and how do I correct it?

```
def binary_search(value, collection):
    if (len(collection) == 0):
        return 0
    checkedValue = binary_search(value, collection[1:])
    return 1 if value == checkedValue else 0

print(binary_search(4, [2, 3, 6, 100]))
print(binary_search(4, [4, 6, 100]))
print(binary_search(4, []))
```

Comment: You never compare an element of the collection and `value`. This isn't searching for anything.

Comment: Also, this is not binary search as you're not reducing your search candidates in half.

Comment: You can give me an example what you mean of binary search for this code?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking your desired value against the return value of the search.  In the given case, you're check `4` against `1` or `0`, which will always evaluate to `False`.

Also, note that you *never* check the first value in the list: you immediately chop it off and recur on the remaining list.  You have no way to identify the value.

```
def binary_search(value, collection):

    if (len(collection) == 0):
        return False

    return True if value == collection[0]  \ 
           else binary_search(value, collection[1:])
```

Result:

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it, its make much more sense now :)
I just debugged it for 5 minutes, and I got the point.